# Getting "BCFKS KeyStore corrupted: MAC calculation failed." error

Tags: oracle, certificate, ssl-certificate, jks

I have a jks file and when i run the command `keytool -keystore  db-ssl-truststore.jks -list` , i get the error 
`keytool error: java.io.IOException: BCFKS KeyStore corrupted: MAC calculation failed.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you created keystore in BCFS format using the Bouncy Castle library.
If you want to see it in human-readable format, you can specify **-storetype**, **-provider** and **-providerpath** options for keytool:

```
keytool -keystore keystore.bckfs -storetype BCFKS -providerpath "bc-fips-1.0.2.jar" -provider org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider -list -v
```